# Drawing a gameboard like checkers in Android

Tags: android

I want to design a gameboard such as Checkers (but with the possibility of having different board tiles.

Now, OO logic and reason tell me I should have a 'tile' class which I can draw, and I draw x by y number of these on one canvas.

My question is what is the best performant way to draw such a board?
Is it reasonable to do it the way I mentioned above and re-draw on changes?
Is it better to have an image as my background and 'simulate' a board by snapping to where the tile would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you might benefit from checking out the snake game code for android. It has a very straight forward way of using tiles to make a game area.

Comment: I did take a look at it, but I'm not sure if that is the best(performant) way to do it. And will Android only re-draw the updated area? Or the entire board?

Comment: You call view.invalidate to refresh. You can pass it a rect

Comment: schwiz - care to explain please?

Comment: @Steve - It will redraw the entire board.

Comment: @Biff - that's what I thought. Anyone have any other solutions to this?

Comment: @Steve - I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Redrawing the entire screen is pretty standard. I do not think you will notice performance issues for tile based game.

Comment: Biff - I guess I'm confused. Do I have one view class and create another 'tile class' and in the view class I lay out each of the tiles, which are views itself? I'm a bit confused on the best approach for designing this thing, to where it is efficient and would only redraw the parts that are changed and not the whole thing.