# include class from another android project

Tags: android

i'm following the suggestion in this post: [Drawing a gameboard like checkers in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791164/drawing-a-gameboard-like-checkers-in-android)

basically, the suggestion in the other thread is that the snake demo in the android SDK has a custom view that display a grid of images suitable for a tile based game, such as snake or checkers, and to base the done on that.

if i just wanted to use this code, how would i do so? i'm using the eclipse IDE with the android toolkit installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanted to you could link the source code to be used in your project via symlinks.  This is probably the quickest way to include code, though you may bring in other stuff that you may not want.

Another way would be to copy the view (+source dependencies) into your src directory on the filesystem then fix any package issues you may have.